# Get birthdate from google plus contacts in circle

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I am trying to get the birthdays of all contacts as well as my own by unable to retrieve such information. Everything else works and I can fetch the name, id, picture, and the contacts in my circle, as well as my own, but the birthday is seems to be null.
This is even after making my birthday public and the birthdays of the contacts are public.

To fetch my details

```
if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mgoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mgoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mgoogleApiClient);

            Log.e("details", "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl + "   ID:" + currentPerson.getId()
                    + "  bday" + currentPerson.getBirthday());
        }
```

To fetch friends list details

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mgoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                if (loadPeopleResult.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                    PersonBuffer personBuffer = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer();
                    try {
                        int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            Log.i("person", "Person " + i + " name: " + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName() + " - id: " + personBuffer.get(i).getId());
                            Log.i("birthday", personBuffer.get(i).getBirthday() + "" + "  hasBday" + personBuffer.get(i).hasBirthday());
                        }
                    } finally {
                        personBuffer.close();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("error", "Error");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, go to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.html#loadConnected%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%29), you will find that:

> **public abstract PendingResult loadVisible**
>   **(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, String pageToken)**
>
> Loads the list of visible people in the user's circles. For more
>   information, see:
>   https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list.
>
> Each Person will contain the **id, displayName, image, objectType, and**
>   **url** fields populated. To retrieve *additional profile data*, use the
>   **load(GoogleApiClient, String...)** method.

So, try using

```
load(GoogleApiClient, String...)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't work,according to that call only users that are using the same app would be displayed and currently its a test app so its 0.

Comment: Test app? What do you mean?

Comment: I'm currently developing the app so no one else could've granted the app permissions to use their profile,in case that made a difference.